# Loading UCI datasets in Mathematica

Tags: data

I'm looking for way to load [UCI datasets](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/datasets) in Mathematica.

Currently these datasets provide a Python interface like below. I'm looking for Mathematica equivalent

```
# !pip install ucimlrepo

from ucimlrepo import fetch_ucirepo 
  
# fetch dataset 
iris = fetch_ucirepo(id=53) 
  
# data (as pandas dataframes) 
X = iris.data.features 
y = iris.data.targets 
  
# metadata 
print(iris.metadata) 
  
# variable information 
print(iris.variables)
```

Comment: The python example is unfortunately not very helpful here, since it just calls an ad hoc function. Describe the structure of the dataset files instead.

Comment: `f[id_] := Import[StringTemplate["https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/``/data.csv"][id], "CSV"] ;
f[53]`

Comment: `ExternalEvaluate` to load with Python and transfer to Mathematica? :)